# vba How to Bubble Sort with two Criteria

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting, bubble-sort

I have an Array of txt like this:

- "Unique text  |05||001|"
- "Unique text  |04||001|"
- "Unique text  |05||002|"
- "Unique text  |04||002|"
- "Unique text  |05||003|"
- "Unique text  |08||003|"
- "Unique text  |04||003|"
- "Unique text  |05||004|"

I have managed to sort this array with bubble Sort, choosing the 2nd set of numbers "001,001,002,002,003...." But i will also like to sort with the first set of numbers as well. Result like this:

- "Unique text  |04||001|"
- "Unique text  |05||001|"
- "Unique text  |04||002|"
- "Unique text  |05||002|"
- "Unique text  |04||003|"
- "Unique text  |05||003|"
- "Unique text  |08||003|"
- "Unique text  |05||004|"

Any idea of how I could structure my bubble sort?
Do i need at new For loop inside my regulare bubble sort?

Current Code (This will Only sort based on 2nd set of numbers). 104 = position of last set of numbers

```
    For i = 1 To UbndCellDataExcel - 1
      For j = i + 1 To UbndCellDataExcel
        If Mid(CellDataExcel(i), 104, 3) > Mid(CellDataExcel(j), 104, 3) Then   
            strTemp = CellDataExcel(i)
            CellDataExcel(i) = CellDataExcel(j)
            CellDataExcel(j) = strTemp
        End If
      Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: a way to do it is to use a concatenation of  the 2 fields in your comparaison

Comment: Can you show us your code, please? What you are asking sounds quite trivial. You would just add the comparison on the first set of numbers to the condition to tell if one row is smaller than the other. Something like (RowA.Col2 > RowB.Col2 AND RowA.Col1 > RowB.Col1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the solution is the compare function:

There are 2 main ways to do this:
The first and the most simple is - to create a new number and sort by it

```
convert "Unique text |05||001|" to "00105"
convert "Unique text |04||002|" to "00204"
00204>00105 so "Unique text |04||002|" > "Unique text |05||001|"
```

More correct and a bit more complicated to do is to simply do 2 compares:

```
Function compare (ByVal i As String,ByVal j As String)
    i1=getParam(1,i)
    i2=getParam(2,i)
    j1=getParam(1,j)
    j1=getParam(2,j)
    if (i1>j1) return 1
    if (i2<j2) return -1
    if (j1>j1) return 1
    if (j2<j2) return -1
    return 0
```

Where `getParam` is function that takes "Unique text |04||002|" and returns "04" or "002".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you מתן ל ! This is what I have now implemented based on your idea to convert:

```
convert "Unique text |05||001|" to "00105"
convert "Unique text |04||002|" to "00204"
```

My code looks like this now (100 = position of first set of number, and 104 is the 2nd set of numbers):

```
    For i = 1 To UbndCellDataExcel - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UbndCellDataExcel
        If Mid(CellDataExcel(i), 104, 3) & Mid(CellDataExcel(i), 100, 2) > Mid(CellDataExcel(j), 104, 3) & Mid(CellDataExcel(j), 100, 2) Then   'Sorter basert på OUnr
            strTemp = CellDataExcel(i)
            CellDataExcel(i) = CellDataExcel(j)
            CellDataExcel(j) = strTemp
        End If
    Next j
Next i


'Mid(CellDataExcel(i), 104, 3) & Mid(CellDataExcel(i), 100, 2) returns Format: "00105"
```